# Display modal Silverlight popup on HTML button click

Tags: silverlight

I have the following desired workflow: on HTML button click a Silverlight modal popup (dialog) must be displayed. No Silverlight content is displayed before HTML button click and no Silverlight content must be displayed after exiting from modal SL popup.

According to our customer inclination we couldn't use another technology for such popups.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish mentioned workflow?

I'm quite new to Silverlight so all the ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: You've misstaged your question. This is not silverlight issue, but html/javascript one.

Comment: This isn't an issue (silverlight/javascript/html or whatever). From my assumption only people with silverlight skill could answer this question. And as silverlight is extremely tightly coupled with DHTML I've decided to tag this question as 'silverlight' only

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is a little unusual, but here goes...

I am assuming you have a Silverlight test project and know enough HTML/JScript to popup a window, as you tagged this question as *Silverlight* only.

Think of Silverlight as just another component you can put on a web page. Any web page. It can be a small control, or fill a HTML window.

In your case you want to simply put your Silverlight startup code into a html page that a popup window can show. The popup window will be triggered by JScript attached to a button.

The Silverlight startup code is usually generated for you in a HTML test webpage in your Silverlight Webproject. Copy it from there.

If you need more detailed instructions for a specific example, please provide more detail.

Comment: Actually the whole Silverlight popup must be modal. I have not enough HTML/JScript experience to accomplish this thru opening new window. Maybe I could leverage creating new div, placing IFRAME there and loading a silverlight app in that iframe? Moreover, somehow I must pass an init parameters for that SL application